# ASP.NET Core cannot sort grouped items

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following model in my ASP.NET Core application:

```
public class LocationTypeGroup {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LocationType> LocationTypes { get; set; } 
}

public class LocationType
{

    [Key]
    public int LocationTypeID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IntExt { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to run a query that groups them by IntExt, and sorts by Name within each group.

The following works, but doesn't sort:

```
    public async Task<List<LocationTypeGroup>> GetGroupedLocationTypes()
    {
        return await _context.LocationTypes
            .GroupBy(p => p.IntExt)
            .Select(g => new LocationTypeGroup
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                LocationTypes = g.Select(x => x)
            })
            .OrderBy(x=>x.Name)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

If I change to this:

```
LocationTypes = g.Select(x => x).OrderBy(x => x)
```

Then I still do not get a sorted result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that EF can't build SQL query.

So you need simplify it manually. and split to 2 queries:

```cs
var groups = await context.LocationTypes
                          .GroupBy(p => p.IntExt)
                          .ToListAsync();

return groups.Select(g => new LocationTypeGroup
              {
                  Name = g.Key,
                  LocationTypes = g.Select(x => x)
              })
             .OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
```

The first query loads simply groups, and the second sorts them and converts to `LocationTypeGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

May be it caused by too old version of Entity Framework Core. Try this approach, moreover it will be less expensive:

```
//data is loaded into memory
var data = await _context.LocationTypes.ToListAsync();
//data's transform
var answer = data.GroupBy(x => x.IntExt)
                 .Select(x => new LocationTypeGroup
                 {
                     Name = x.Key,
                     LocationTypes = x.AsEnumerable()
                 }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```